# WCF An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I getting this error  :`An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException'`

full discripton of error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP
>   response to
>   http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SnUpdateService/Service1/.
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
>   aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
>   server logs for more details.

When in clien i am trying to get response with stream data

```
  SnUpdateService.Service1Client SnService = new     SnUpdateService.Service1Client();
       SnUpdateService.UpdateFiles com = new SnUpdateService.UpdateFiles();
       com.Path = "C:\\temp";
       com.SearchType = 1;
       com.Version = "20150101";
       SnUpdateService.UpdateFiles comReturn = new SnUpdateService.UpdateFiles();
       comReturn = SnService.GetUpdateFiles(com);//here error
```

if there is no stream data all work fine.

What i am doing wrong?

This my client config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferPoolSize="200000000"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" />
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SnUpdateService/Service1/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="SnUpdateService.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

This my server webConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SnUpdateService.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SnUpdateService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SnUpdateService.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the definition for the binding configuration **BasicHttpBinding_IService1** in client configuration file.

Also, you can set includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" to "true" to get more detailed stack trace. Which helps you debug.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem some time back and resolved it by enabling 32-Bit applications in the app pool where my service was hosted.

Comment: Can you please provide an example showing your answer?